# What is the easiest way to convert uppercase special character to lower case special character?

Tags: javascript, events

I have an event handler which gives the key pressed. I want to have an equivalent character obtained when not holding the `shift` key.

I found that the difference in the character code for upper and lower case is different for different special characters.

For letters , in js , i do `value.toLowerCase()` but this only works on letters and not special chars.

Without finding any automated way , i ended up writing this mapping manually :

```
const getLowerCaseMap = (val:string)=>{
    //function gets a string of length 1
    switch(val){
        case '~' : return '`' ; 
        case '{' : return '[' ; 
        case '}' : return ']' ; 
        case '"' : return "'" ; 
        case ':' : return ";" ; 
        case '>' : return "." ; 
        case '<' : return "," ; 
        case '?' : return "/" ; 
        case '|' : return "\\" ; 
        case '_' : return "-" ; 
        case '!' : return '1' ; 
        case '@' : return '2' ; 
        case '#' : return '3' ; 
        case '$' : return '4' ; 
        case '%' : return '5' ; 
        case '^' : return '6' ; 
        case '&' : return '7' ; 
        case '*' : return '8' ; 
        case '(' : return '9' ; 
        case ')' : return '0' ; 
        default : return val.toLowerCase()
    }
}
```

Is there any function in javascript or hack that makes this possible writing without the above mapping function  ?

Comment: It is **not-correct** to assume that `[` is the lowercase version of `{`... They're just different chars. The fact that you can switch them via `shift` it is only because you're using an *english keyboard*

Comment: different keyboard can have different mappings, so there's not automatic or native function to do such thing, if the mapping you have above cover all your cases then it's fine, but you can't take it for granted if your use case is to cover all of the cases

Answer (score 1):

Shorter (and faster?) version. Don't have the mapper definition inside the function

```js
const mapper = { '~': '`', '{': '[', '}': ']', '"': "'", ':': ",", '>': ".", '<': ",", '?': "/", '|': "\\", '_': "-", '!': '1', '@': '2', '#': '3', '$': '4', '%': '5', '^': '6', '&': '7', '*': '8', '(': '9', ')': '0', }
Object.freeze(mapper); // making @Code_Maniac happier
const getLowerCaseMap = (val => mapper[val] ||  val.toLowerCase())

console.log(getLowerCaseMap('A'))
console.log(getLowerCaseMap('('))
```

Comment: But how about immutability, since it is an object so it can be mutated, if it is a part of large code base there are chances that you can mutate unintentionally, which can cause problem, where as when you keep it inside function it will be less prone to such problems

Comment: I have never had such an issue. If you are going to rapidly call your function with reams of text then you certainly should cache the map

Comment: @CodeManiac you could [`freeze`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) the object

Comment: this happens when you call it in a infinite loop, In such cases a curried function will be a better option,

Comment: I am sure curry is far above OPs head for the moment

Comment: this is shorter, but I don't think it would be faster.

Comment: oh, you're comparing to @CodeManiac 's version, I guess. Still don't think it would make much difference, anyway.

Comment: @mplungjan this was indeed a gold `making @Code_Maniac happier`,  This [`Test`](http://jsben.ch/uroNR) shows otherwise about speed,

Comment: @CodeManiac Any suggestion as to why?

Comment: Also your tests do not use const `const mapper = { '~': '\`', '{': '[', '}': ']', '"': "'", ':': ",", '>': ".", '<': ",", '?': "/", '|': "\\", '_': "-", '!': '1', '@': '2', '#': '3', '$': '4', '%': '5', '^': '6', '&': '7', '*': '8', '(': '9', ')': '0' };
const getLowerCaseMap = val => mapper[val] || val.toLowerCase();`

Comment: @mplungjan i am not able to run this test, it stuck at `25%` :(

Comment: Annoying tool. The onel I have on screen works - saved one not

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use an `object` as mapper instead of `switch`, to mimic `default` of switch you check the existence of key in object if it's there return respective value else lowercase it

```js
const getLowerCaseMap = (val) => {
  let mapper = {
    '~': '`',
    '{': '[',
    '}': ']',
    '"': "'",
    ':': ",",
    '>': ".",
    '<': ",",
    '?': "/",
    '|': "\\",
    '_': "-",
    '!': '1',
    '@': '2',
    '#': '3',
    '$': '4',
    '%': '5',
    '^': '6',
    '&': '7',
    '*': '8',
    '(': '9',
    ')': '0',
  }
  return val in mapper ? mapper[val] : val.toLowerCase()
}

console.log(getLowerCaseMap('A'))
console.log(getLowerCaseMap('('))
```